# Getting wrong sub-matrix from a matrix with an error of -1

Tags: java, image-preprocessing, kadanes-algorithm

I am trying to find out the maximum sum sub matrix of size k from a 2d matrix.

I have implemented everything correctly, but still I'm getting:

> index out of bounds -1 exception

The idea I'm following for this thing as follows:

1. Preprocess the the original matrix into `pre_processes[][]` so that I can find sm in constant time.
2. Start from index k-1 fro both row and column if any of them row-k or col-k is greater than 0 subtract that from the current sum
   if both are greater add their union which will be at `pre_processes[row-1][column-1]`

**Code:**

```
public int max_sum(int[][] image,int k ){
    int[][] pre_processed = new int[image.length][image[0].length];
    pre_processed[0][0] = image[0][0];
    for (int row = 1;row < image.length-k+1;row++){
        pre_processed[row][0] += image[row][0] + pre_processed[row-1][0];
    }

    for (int column = 1;column < image.length-k+1;column++){
        pre_processed[0][column] += image[0][column] + pre_processed[0][column-1];
    }

    for (int rows = 1;rows < image.length;rows++){
        for (int columns = 1;columns < image[0].length;columns++){
            pre_processed[rows][columns] = pre_processed[rows-1][columns]+pre_processed[rows][columns-1]+
                                           image[rows][columns]-pre_processed[rows-1][columns];
        }
    }

    int total,brightness = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int row_2 = k-1;row_2 < image.length;row_2++){
        for (int col_2 = k-1;col_2 < image[0].length;col_2++){

            total = pre_processed[row_2][col_2];
            if (row_2-k > 0)
                total -= pre_processed[row_2-k][col_2];
            if (col_2-k > 0)
                total -= pre_processed[row_2][col_2-k];
            if (row_2-k > 0 && col_2-k > 0)
                total += pre_processed[row_2-1][col_2-1];
            if (total > brightness)
                brightness = total;
        }
    }

    return brightness;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] image = {
        {2 ,  3,   4, 10, 12},
        {20 , 30, 14, 11, 13},
        {29 , 39, 40, 12, 24},
        {40 , 39, 39, 15, 35},
        {100 ,23, 24, 60, 80}
    };
}
```

Comment: Please post [mre]. You initialize image but do not use it. Add the whole error message (stack trace) and mark the line that throws the error.  Add the expected output of the test case you use please. Format your code and folllow java naming conventions to make it more readable. Also the text it hard to read: not a single period in it.